# What is the limit of $\frac{3^n}{2^n+3^n}$ as $n$ goes to infinity?

Tags: limits

I'd like a general solution too, if possible!

> Also, why is $$\lim_{n\to\infty}n\sin\left(\frac1n\right)=1?$$

Is it because $\sin \left(\frac1n\right)$ tends to $0$ at a decreasing rate compared to the regular rate at which $n$ tends to infinity?

Thanks.

Comment: $$\frac{3^n}{2^n+3^n} = \frac{1}{(2/3)^n+1}$$

Comment: @Shaun: your edit left out the n before the sine term. That's crucial. Tried editing it in, but it's less than 6 characters and the software won't let me.

Comment: @Deepak Sorry. Of course, yeah. I'll correct it :)

Comment: Keep questions distinct in future. Even if they both correspond to analysis, it is better to have two questions than just one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both of these limits can be handled with some rewriting -- for the first one:
$$
\frac{3^n}{2^n+3^n}=\frac{1}{(2/3)^n+1}
$$
Now look at what happens to $(2/3)^n$ as $n\to\infty$.

For $n\cdot\sin(1/n)$, again rewrite:
$$
n\cdot\sin(1/n)=\frac{\sin(1/n)}{1/n}
$$
and now look at what happens to $1/n$ as $n\to\infty$...

Answer (score 1):

hint: divide through $3^n$. What do you get?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are mistaken, $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sin(1/n)=0$, and  $\lim_{n\to\infty}\cos(1/n)=1$, this is because  $\lim_{n\to\infty}1/n=0$, and $\sin(0)=0,\cos(0)=1$

Now lets approach the first question, simply divide through by $3^n$ to obtain:

$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{3^n}{2^n+3^n}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{(\frac{2}{3}^n+1)}=1$

Comment: Sorry @ellya. The missing $n$ was my fault. I shouldn't multitask so much . . .

Comment: @Shaun ahh, to realise this see that $\sin(x)=x-x^3/3!+x^5/5!\pm...$